# Why .addEventListener("click" doesnt work on mobile but works on computer?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, mobile, onclick

I have an LWC that works perfect in computers but doesnt work on mobile Devices

```
marker.addEventListener("click", function(e){              // Centra la pantalla al marker seleccionado
            component.map.panTo(this.getLatLng());
            var layer = e.target;
            layer.setIcon(layer.options.icon == myIconSelected ? myIcon : myIconSelected);
        });
        var callback = $A.getCallback(function(event) {
            var pubsub = component.find('pubsub');
            pubsub.fireEvent(
                'dreamhouse__propertySelected',
                event.target.propertyId
            );
        });                                                      
        marker.on('click', callback);
```

When i click the marker on the map dont do anything on mobile.

Comment: AFAIK `$A.getCallback` is not supported by LWC, is the code on aura/LWC component?

Comment: alternative to get click event?

Comment: Sory, its AURA, not LWC

Comment: this its not working on mobile either:

marker.addEventListener("click", function(e){              // Centra la pantalla al 
        });